# Select the a set of values in a dataframe and add its values to the tail of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I'm having 2 dataframes like below

```
df=data.frame(D=1:3)
df4=data.frame(A=1:8,B=NA)
```

What I need is to add the values of column D in dataframe, 'df' to the dataframe df4. But the values only need to be added to the tail of the df4 dataframe. So df4$B should be like NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 3

This is just an example. What I need to know is a generic answer which I can use for any 2 dataframes. If I have the dataframe df, I need to a add its content to the last set of values in df4 by replacing column B in dataframe df4

Comment: Can you test the solution below.  It is a general solution (assuming that the first dataset number of rows is less than or equal to the second 'df4')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an index with `tail` on the sequence of rows

```
i1 <- tail(seq_len(nrow(df4)), nrow(df))
df4$B[i1] <- df$D
```

-output

```
df4
#  A  B
#1 1 NA
#2 2 NA
#3 3 NA
#4 4 NA
#5 5 NA
#6 6  1
#7 7  2
#8 8  3
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot. I was searching this. Can you kindly let me know the way of expanding my knowledge to do these stuffs. I think I was fail to search it.

Comment: @user3789200 With programming, better option is to practise, try to solve problems.   Then, only you will understand where you are failing etc.  I would say it is better to get error etc to learn it rather than solving things without any error